# Missing yarn in software-collections

Tags: yarnpkg, software-collections

Yarn is currently the newest package management system for JavaScript, and also the default for Rails 5.1.

Has it been considered to be included in software collections?

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5.1 is currently not in Software Collections and support for Yarn is since Rails 5.1.
You can however use NPM. I'm also not sure about Yarn being default for Rails.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#yarn-support

Comment: Using NPM to install yarn is not recommended for security reasons. 
THe preferred way is to add the yarn repo and do yum install, but that is not available in PaaS systems.